# try catch does not work for std::stoull c++

Tags: c++

`std::stoull()` does not throw any exception for definitely incorrect input.

Example of code, where this problem occurs:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream ss("6yh45gu94j5vun:");
    string valueStr;
    if (!getline(ss, valueStr, ':')) {
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned long long value;
    try {
        value = stoull(valueStr, nullptr, 16);
    } catch (exception& e) {
        cout << -1;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << value;
}
```

I tried to catch every single exception, but still doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: What are the contents of `valueStr`?

Comment: What's an example of incorrect input, and what does `k.value` end up being?

Comment: Are you taking into account that `stoull()` may only be parsing a portion of `valueStr` without failing? Like `operator>>`, it parses only as much as it needs, and can leave part of the input unparsed. You have to use the 2nd output parameter to know if the entire string was consumed or not.

Comment: @user253751 [yes, it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul): "*Exceptions - `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed - `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (`std::strtoul` or `std::strtoull`) sets `errno` to `ERANGE`.*"

Comment: Can you explain how to use 2nd output parameter?

Comment: @mcyrill [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/03mJ7v), `stoull()` does throw an exception on the input you have shown

Comment: Your example [throws an exception here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35ac47012b04158f).  You can see how to use the second parameter [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f32af4bfb1c240b)

Comment: Note that in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76095065/3) of the question, you had originally posted the input `qwedfyguh78yrt65e78ofg78gfrtyuiop`. This input does not reproduce the problem, because it does cause an exception to be thrown. On the other hand, the input `6yh45gu94j5vun`, which is posted in the latest revision of your question, does reproduce the problem, for the reasons stated in my answer. In future, please verify that the input you post actually reproduces the problem, before you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `std::stoull` does not throw an exception because it successfully converted the input to the integer `6`. It will stop reading once it encounters a character it cannot convert. If at least one character was converted, then the conversion is considered successful.

If you want to determine how much of the input it converted, you must use the second parameter of `std::stoull`, instead of setting it to `nullptr`.

In order to use the second parameter, you must define an additional variable

```
std::size_t num_chars_converted;
```

and then call the function like this:

```
value = std::stoull(valueStr, &num_chars_converted, 16);
```

If no exception is thrown, then the variable `num_chars_converted` will contain the number of characters converted. You can then compare that value with the length of the string, in order to determine whether the entire string was converted.